# Meteor: loop with counter

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an object 'obj' that have a numeric value 'count'. I want to add "'count'" images of star to the page. something like:

```
{{#for i=0;i<count;++i}}
<img src="/star.png" style="width: 16px; height: 16px" />
{{/for}}
```

I know this is not valid, but how can I get that behavior?

Answer (score 3):

I believe I found how to do it: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/8ac310b9db204ccb74039b691aae6962d5799fe9/packages/blaze/builtins.js#L75

I think you need to extend Blaze object `Blaze.For` but I don't think you can evaluate `i<count` and `i++`.

A possible implementation by extending Blaze:

```
{{#range 0 count 1}}
{{/range}}
```

Lazy man implementation:

```
Template.yourTemplate.helpers({
    range : function( start , end , inc ){
        return _.range( start , end , inc );
    }
})
```

Still Lazy:

```
{{#with range 0 count 1}}
{{/with}}
```

If you want to the range functionality to Blaze you've to handle a lot.